Replication from Artifactory got problem with manifest_unknown
I am trying to move away from Artifactory with all docker images into Harbor.
I have created replication rule to run on pull-based from Artifactory to Harbor.
Currently none of the images were able to replicate.
In jobservice.log file I found
[ERROR] [/controller/replication/transfer/image/transfer.go:470]: failed to pull the manifest of artifact docker-dev-local/XXX/gfx_apps_via_jenkins/ort_nv_bert_base_uncased:6.2.0-13963-ubuntu: http status code: 404, body: {"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"The named manifest is not known to the registry.","detail":{"manifest":"docker-dev-local/XXX/gfx_apps_via_jenkins/ort_nv_bert_base_uncased"}}]}
When I took a look at Artifactory at this image I can see manifest.json inside:

What I am missing?
Any way to further debug it?
My source manifest.json schema is 2.
Does it have impact on replication since I can read:
Docs that you can not replicate artifacts with manifest list from 2.0 to 1.x.
Does it mean that replication supports only manifests schema version 1?
Thanks in advance,
Michal
